# Drag and Drop Inventory for Game in Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a game inventory for a browser based game in Ruby Rails. Now, i was trying to find some good resources on the topic but i'm unable to locate some good examples. I would like to find something about drag, drop, lock and stuff like ajax refreshing when i drag an element out of the inventory.

Do you happen to know of any good resources, or even a ready made plugin for that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com — Drag and drop goodness, complete with all the events you need to do what you want with making AJAX calls when an item is dragged out of inventory.

AJAX is baked right into jQuery. All you need is your Rails app…

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/ if you were feeling like linking more directly

Comment: thank you, i know about jquery ui though. I was looking for some tutorial or an easier solution, probably already utilizing that, since i wouldn't really want to mess with jquery so much, if that would be feasible.

Comment: @SpyrosP These tools have already done 90% of the work for you. They have to be hooked together somehow, though. If you're unwilling to do the remaining 10%, you should hire someone else to do it or give up.

Comment: @SpyrosP, i am of the opinion that is is physically impossble to design anything simpler to use than a pre-made jQuery plugin. what 'messing' with jQuery are you expecting to do? all you need to do is set a drop event that calls your ajax handler on the server...

Comment: Ok, guys i'm convinced, it indeed seems kinda easy to say the truth. Thanx ;)